# How process special characters in "curl_fetch_memory" requests in R?

Tags: r, curl

I have a code with "curl::curl_fetch_memory" for getting data from REST server. All works fine except processing national characters. Here is a code which generated bugs

```
  # 1. Works
  str_json <- "https://api.company.com/request?name=SEROUJ%20DEBUI"

  # 2. NOT works
  str_json <- "https://api.company.com/request?name=SÉROUJ%20DEBUI"

  # 3. Create new handler
  h <- curl::new_handle()
  curl::handle_setopt(
    handle = h, httpauth = 1,
    userpwd = "password")

  # 4. Using curl
  resp <- curl::curl_fetch_memory(str_json, handle = h)
  rawToChar(resp$content)
  jsonlite::fromJSON(rawToChar(resp$content))
```

The difference between JSON is one char "E" (works) vs "É" (not works). It generates bug "502 Bad Gateway".

Any ideas on how to fix this bug are welcome!

Comment: did you try this - https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.6.2/topics/URLencode

Comment: Just checked it. Not helps.

Comment: I have tried it with a space, and it did the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you do this with a space in the string it seems to work:

```r
str_json <- "https://api.company.com/request?name=SÉROUJ DEBUI"
URLencode(str_json)
# "https://api.company.com/request?name=S%C3%89ROUJ%20DEBUI"
```

For some reason it does not pick it up if you already have some values encoded.

It works in other direction:

```r
URLdecode("https://api.company.com/request?name=S%C3%89ROUJ%20DEBUI")
#[1] "https://api.company.com/request?name=SÉROUJ DEBUI"
```

Comment: Yes, great! Double encoding-decoding fix the issue! Thanks a lot, Bulat!